# How to export result from SQLResultSet into a csv

Tags: streams, sql

I have a sql query which produces very large data from a remote server but the data is too large to fit into memory all at once. So i want to read and export it sequentially into a csv. I am using the following commands:

```
data=SQLResultSetOpen@SQLExecute[databaseLink,query,
"ShowColumnHeadings"->True,"MaxRows"->10000];

Export[path,SQLResultSetRead[data],"CSV"]
```

but i only get one line. But i want to get 10000 lines each time and export and then move to the next 10000 until all data is moved to the csv. Somebody help!!!